# ValueError: No backend available

Tags: python, nfc, backend

I try to use my ACR122U and the nfcpy library/module for Python 2.7 on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

I followed the instruction on this site: http://nfcpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/get-started.html but still get the error when typing:

```
clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')
  File "nfc/clf.py", line 105, in __init__
    if path and not self.open(path):
  File "nfc/clf.py", line 156, in open
    self.dev = nfc.dev.connect(path)
  File "nfc/dev/__init__.py", line 55, in connect
    found = transport.USB.find(path)
  File "nfc/dev/transport.py", line 169, in find
    for d in cls.usb_core.find(find_all=True, **match)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 1199, in find
    raise ValueError('No backend available')
ValueError: No backend available
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a PC/SC daemon running? Do you get any output from the command `pcsctest`?

Comment: `pcsctest

MUSCLE PC/SC Lite Test Program

Testing SCardEstablishContext    : Command successful.
Testing SCardGetStatusChange 
Please insert a working reader   : Command successful.
Testing SCardListReaders         : Command successful.
Reader 01: ACS ACR122U 00 00
Enter the reader number          : 1
Waiting for card insertion         
                                 : Command successful.
Testing SCardConnect             : Card is unpowered.`

Comment: That means that you *have* a PC/SC daemon running. In order to get nfcpy to work with the ACR122U you have to disable that daemon.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not shure if it worked correctly. I now get the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')
  File "nfc/clf.py", line 106, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.ENODEV, os.strerror(errno.ENODEV))
IOError: [Errno 19] Operation not supported by device`